# markers on google maps using Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, google-maps, angular6

I have a list of geolocations in my database and I store them in a variable like this:

.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getListings()
  }

  getListings() {
    this.serviceHomeScreen.getAllListingsDetails().subscribe((data) => {
      this.extractlistings(data[0])
    })
  }

  extractlistings(data) {
    this.locations = data

    console.log(this.locations[1]) // has the right value
  }

  mapReady(map) {
    console.log(this.locations[1]) // undefined

    for (let i = 0; i < this.locations.length; i++) {
      console.log("aici")
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: this.locations[i].lat, lng: this.locations[i].long },
        map: map,
      });
    }
  }
```

.html

```
<agm-map id="map_" [zoom]="30" [fitBounds]="true" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [streetViewControl]="false" [zoomControl]="false" (mapReady)="mapReady($event)"></agm-map>
```

where locations is something like this

`locations = [{'id': 1, 'lat': '43', long: '-12'}, {'id': 2, 'lat': '34', long: '-15'}, {'id': 3, 'lat': '13', long: '-12'}`]

The problem is that I get this `locations` array from the service, it has the right value, but inside `mapReady()` function, when I need the latitude and longitude from the array, is `undefined`.

Why is that? `mapReady` is called before `ngOnInit`?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapReady(map)` is called by an output emitted by the `<agm-map>` component which could be emitted before your `ngOnInit()` has finished completing which is why you would be getting `undefined` for `this.locations`.

Try getting your locations when the map is ready, then you won't get `undefined`.

```
mapReady(map) {

    this.serviceHomeScreen.getAllListingsDetails().subscribe((data) => {
        this.locations = data[0];

        for (let i = 0; i < this.locations.length; i++) {
            console.log("aici")
            return new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: this.locations[i].lat, lng: this.locations[i].long },
                map: map,
            });
       }    
    })            
}
```

Another approach would be to carry on getting the data on `ngOnInit` but set a flag e.g. `this.dataLoaded = true` when the data has finished loading. You would then use this property in an `*ngIf` on the `<agm-map>` component template so that the component only loaded when the data is ready. The data will then be available when (mapReady) is emitted and `mapReady(map)` is called.

```
dataLoaded = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getListings()
}

getListings() {
    this.serviceHomeScreen.getAllListingsDetails().subscribe((data) => {
      this.extractlistings(data[0]);
    })
}

extractlistings(data) {
    this.locations = data;
    this.dataLoaded = true;
    console.log(this.locations[1]); // has the right value
}

mapReady(map) {

    console.log(this.locations[1]); // now defined

    for (let i = 0; i < this.locations.length; i++) {
        console.log("aici")
        return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: this.locations[i].lat, lng: this.locations[i].long },
                map: map,
        });
    }              
}
```

Template:

```
<agm-map 
*ngIf="dataLoaded" 
id="map_" 
[zoom]="30" 
[fitBounds]="true" 
[latitude]="lat" 
[longitude]="lng" 
[streetViewControl]="false" 
[zoomControl]="false" 
(mapReady)="mapReady($event)">
</agm-map>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is in mapReady being called before ngOnInit, but more that mapReady is getting called before the getAllListingsDetails returns a value.

One way to get around waiting for the map to be ready, since you're using angular-maps, is to use the `<agm-marker>` directive inside of `<agm-map>`.

For example:

```
<agm-map>
            <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
                        [latitude]="m.lat"
                        [longitude]="m.lng"
                        label="{{ i + 1 }}">
                <agm-info-window>
                    <strong>InfoWindow content</strong>
                </agm-info-window>
            </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: This was my previous solution, but I wanted to do this way, because it's easier for what I want to develop next. Thank you, anyway!